# Javascript event listener not being removed

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

I'm having an issue were the event listener is not being removed, each time the gameLoop func is called again its doing eveything 2x, 4x, ect.. every time the game loop rolls around.

```
function gameLoop(data) {
    let currentQuestion = newQuestion(data); // randomizes the question

    displayAnswers.forEach(element => { // removes the added classes to show if the answer is right or wrong
        element.classList.remove('correct');
        element.classList.remove('incorrect');
        element.removeEventListener('click', handleAnswerClick); // remove the event listener IS NOT WORKING
    });

    renderUi(currentQuestion); //loads Q/A to screen

    displayAnswers.forEach(element => { 
        element.addEventListener('click', handleAnswerClick);
    });

    function handleAnswerClick(event) {
        checkAnswer(event, currentQuestion, data);
    }
}
```

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xOrqXAdbzW0Xsr1nplK0hzcGJQrLbPog?usp=sharing - here is the code with a video of the bug in action

Comment: the reason is simple, everytime gameLoop runs it creates a new handleAnswerClick function, to remove an event listener you need to pass the same function registered with addEventListener, so try to move handleAnswerClick outside of gameLoop or save a reference to it

Comment: One way to save reference to the function would be to attach it as a property to the DOM element. Or, if there are no other event listeners being juggled, you can simply use good old DOM level 2 `onclick` property and reset that.

Comment: just remove this line `element.addEventListener('click', handleAnswerClick);`, and   also prefer to use `element.classList.remove('correct','incorrect');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `handleAnswerClick` in the local scope of `gameLoop`. The reference to the function is not available when a second call is made to `gameLoop`. Since `handleAnswerClick` is defined with the `function` statement, it is accessible directly from the start of the `gameLoop` function, and it is then incorrectly passed to removeEventListener.

The issue happens somewhat like this:

```
gameLoop()[run 1]:
- function handleAnswerClick(...){...}//Even if defined at the end, 
//functions defined with the function keyword 
//are available inside the scope they were defined in [here:gameLoop() local scope] at all times
- addEventListener(...)
gameLoop()[run 2]:
- removeEventListener(...)//This is where the issue is.
//In the second call, a new handleAnswerClick is defined into the local scope,
//this is a different local scope than the first one.
//now, the new handleAnswerClick, which is different than the old handleAnswerClick,
//is passed to removeEventListener. removeEventListener does not throw an error if a 
//unregistered function is passed, it ignores it instead. This applies to the new function, 
//as the old function is the one that was registered, and the new function is different from it
- ...
gameLoop()[run X]:
- ...
```

your new function should look like this:

```
function gameLoop(data) {
    let currentQuestion = newQuestion(data); // randomizes the question

    displayAnswers.forEach(element => { // removes the added classes to show if the answer is right or wrong
        element.classList.remove('correct');
        element.classList.remove('incorrect');
        element.removeEventListener('click', window.lastClickHandlerFunction); //will be undefined on first call, later it is the correct function
    });

    renderUi(currentQuestion); //loads Q/A to screen

    displayAnswers.forEach(element => { 
        element.addEventListener('click', handleAnswerClick);
    });
    window.lastClickHandlerFunction=handleAnswerClick;//Store a reference to the registered function
    function handleAnswerClick(event) {
        checkAnswer(event, currentQuestion, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Also Check: Event Delegation

Maybe worth mentioning that instead of adding and removing event listeners of every target element (with fix well demonstrated in the selected answer), it is also possible to use [**event delegation**](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)

That would mean you'd not have to care about adding and removing listeners on items at all, or more precisely have just single event listener sitting above all (potential) targets and tap into event propagation on that single parent DOM node, watching what happens underneath.